# Unicode chars cause error in Apache TomEE: Character decoding failed. Parameter _ with value _ has been ignored. ...DecodeException: isHexDigit

Tags: java, urlencode, apache-tomee

In a java app running in Apache Tomee, I need to handle some HTTP Requests.

Some of them might contain special characters in the query, like: `FolderName=sc ß ü ä ö`, and this arrives encoded like this `FolderName=sc+%u00df+%u00fc+%u00e4+%u00f6`.

Because of this, I get this exception in the TomEE server log:
`2022-02-18 13:26:05 FINE   org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters processParameters Character decoding failed. Parameter [FolderName] with value [sc+%u00df+%u00fc+%u00e4+%u00f6] has been ignored. org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.UDecoder$DecodeException: isHexDigit`

This seems to be some non-stadard encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#Non-standard_implementations.

**I have no control over how the request is sent to me**, so I need to handle this in the Java app.

What can I do ?

Thanks.